# Table Adapter not updating after adding parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, tableadapter

I'm quite new to .NET and very new to TableAdapters. I am currently working on updating an existing program and am required to alter some SQL code to update a field in one of the databases where I work. I've changed my VB and code and everything in terms of my UI is good to go so I am now trying to update the TableAdapter that is used to account for my change.

I am adding a parameter (@jobNumber) and wish to update the field 'DISCRETE_JOB' in the database table I'm working in.

I've added in the 'DISCRETE_JOB' parameter to my INSERT INTO statement as the third parameter and added the '@jobNumber' as the third parameter in the VALUES() line of my SQL.

After Finishing the changes are there when I bring up the tool-tip (by hovering mouse over the TableAdapter Query) but the actual parameters listed beside the name of the Query int the **DataSet.xsd** file are not updated

Looks like-> InsertData(@Param1,@Param2,@Param3)

Should look like ->  InsertData(@Param1, @Param2, @jobNumber, @Param3)

Even after saving changes to the .xsd file the parameters don't SHOW the changes of parameters. I also took a look at the **DataSet.Designer.vb** file for the **DataSet.xsd** file and it doesn't appear that my new parameter has been taken into account.

Again, I am new and there may be a couple of things I'm supposed to do to make these changes happen, but I just don't want to mess anything up, as there's a lot of queries in the file for this program.

Thanks! Let me know if I need to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I fixed my problem, though I'm still not sure exactly what was going on and why the parameters weren't updated automatically.

Here's the fix:

The SQL code I added remained in place, but I needed to manually add the parameter I wanted. To do this I went to the properties of the query in question and clicked 'Add', filling in the correct fields based on what the existing parameters looked like as a guide line.

Hopefully this can help someone else too!